# i need to get three select for day, month, year in one variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to get select drop down date into one table

```
$rent=$_POST['rent_day'] $_POST['rent_month'] $_POST['rent_year'];
```

I think this is wrong, Please I need correction.

```
<select name="rent_day" id="day" >

<select name="rent_month" id="month" >

<select name="rent_year" id="year" >
```

Comment: Use the dot operator to append string values in PHP. $rent=$_POST['rent_day'] . "-" . $_POST['rent_month'] . "-" . $_POST['rent_year']; Then convert to a date object and continue.

Comment: okay, i gat you, let me try this

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get values in php from a POST request then do something with the date value, correct?

Comment: `<input id="date" type="date">` is nce for both you and your users. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to get values in php from a POST request then do something with the date value.

I agree it would look much better in UX terms using some sort of date picker.

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$rent = $_POST['rent_day'] . "/" . $_POST['rent_month'] . "/" . $_POST['rent_year'];

$rentDate = $dt->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $rent);

// Can read it using:
echo $rentDate->format('Y-m-d');

// Update table with date
```